# R Kable: How to remove to \cmidrule from one column?

Tags: r, kable

I'm trying to use `Kable` to add a header row to my table. My code is:

```
latex <- kbl(df, format='latex', booktabs = T, escape = F, digits=3, col.names = labst) %>% 
  add_header_above(c("Year" = 1, "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2" = 2, "Group 3" = 2, "Group 4" = 2))
```

I only want the `\cmidrule` line below the Group 1-3 headers and not below Year. Does someone know how I can remove the line for only one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. You can use the `extra_latex_after` option to add custom lines.

```
latex <- kbl(df, format='latex', booktabs = T, escape = F, digits=3, col.names = labst) %>% 
  add_header_above(c("Year" = 1, "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2" = 2, "Group 3" = 2, "Group 4" = 2), line=F) %>%
  row_spec(c(1)-2, extra_latex_after = "\\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-3} \\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){4-5} \\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){6-7} \\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){8-9}")
```